# Why not using service() instead of doPost() and doGet()?

Tags: java, jsp

I am very new to Java. I have a script which works fine but I would like to understand the logic behind of it.

If a user types in his username, I would like to output the same.

I am using

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

but from many tutorials I see

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

and

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
```

I think that I understand the differences between `doGet()` and `doPost()`. Both of them will be called by the method `service()`. So why would I use `doGet()` and `doPost()`, if I could simply use `service()`?

My whole code looks like this:

```
package ch.yourclick.zt;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(req.getParameter("username"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override `service` your servlet will handle all request methods (`GET`, `POST`, ...). These request methods have different meanings and are expected to behave in different ways, see [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Your servlet will therefore fail to return correct responses for some of these and the user of your servlet might be confused, e.g. why a `DELETE` behaves the same way like a `GET` and does not actually modify the source.

Additionally depending on what your servlet does, it might introduce security vulnerabilities, for example when your servlet (which also handles `GET`) modifies a database.